# Android - How to do bulk updates on a contentresolver

Tags: android

I use a for loop on a ArrayList and if the condition is satisfied i do a update on my content resolver one by one.

Is it possible to do a bulk update on the content resolver ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ContentProvider.applyBatch(...)

[ContentProvider Batch Operation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#applyBatch%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E%29)